# Find current owner of custom data type?

Tags: postgresql, permissions, postgresql-9.1, datatypes

In Postgresql, when I try to run `ALTER TYPE x ADD VALUE y;` on a custom datatype I get an error stating `PG::Error: ERROR: must be owner of type x`.

I know this can be solved by running `ALTER TYPE x OWNER TO <database owner>` but what I'm curious about is how I can check the current owner of this specific datatype. `\dT+ x` does not give me information about the current owner.

How can I extract more information about custom data types, including the current owner?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Up until 9.4

You can go and ask the system catalogs ([`pg_type`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/catalog-pg-type.html), to be precise):

```
SELECT rolname 
  FROM pg_type t 
  JOIN pg_authid r ON typowner = r.oid 
 WHERE typname = 'bla';

 usename 
─────────
 dezso
```

### From PostgreSQL 9.5 on

From this version on, there is a new [object identifier type](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-oid.html) called `regrole`, and it makes the query a bit simpler:

```
SELECT typowner::regrole 
  FROM pg_type t 
 WHERE typname = 'bla';
```

But there is more to it - the new 9.5 version of `psql` already displays the owner when using `\dT+`:

```
      Schema       | Name | Internal name | Size | Elements |  Owner   | ...
-------------------+------+---------------+------+----------+----------+ ...
 zel_api_r14_00_09 | bla  | bla           | 4    | a        | postgres | ...
```